# Did R Aaron Feldman and R Lichtenstein ever meet before the latter's death?

Tags: rabbis

R Lichtenstein and R Feldman had a dialog in Jewish Action: https://jewishaction.com/letters/dear_reb_aharon/

I'm wondering if they ever actually followed through on their stated desire to meet, and if so, what topics and perspectives on yiddishkeit were expressed.

Comment: You mean meet *again*, in their old age; they knew each other in their youth.

Comment: Even more important, when they met did they manage to go sledding?

Comment: Is this about Judaism? Or Jews? @DoubleAA

Comment: Adding: I'm curious in the event there was a meeting, what was discussed, and what perspectives on yiddishkeit were contained therein

Comment: @robev I'm not sure

Comment: `if so, what topics and perspectives on yiddishkeit were expressed` seems to make it a very Judaism oriented question